# Create rows and append to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a dataframe with the rows and columns defined like this

```
     1   2   3   4
 A
 B
 C
```

and fill it with two loops. I have written this:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
cnt = 0
for l2 in range(len(list2)):
    vec = []
    for l1 in range(len(list1)):
        vec.append(cnt)
        cnt += 1
    tmp_row = {list2[l2], vec}   # <-- Error
    tmp = pd.DataFrame([tmp_row])
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, tmp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print(df1)
```

So at the first iteration of outer loop, I expect to have

```
     1   2   3   4
 A   0   1   2   3
```

and then

```
     1   2   3   4
 A   0   1   2   3
 B   4   5   6   7
```

and so on. However, at the `tmp_row`, I get this error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I fix the error?

---

**Update**:

In this snippet, I used a counter. In my code, that is not a simple counter. So, assume something like:

```
cnt = foo()
vec.append(cnt)
```

So, a row is something like `A 0.2 0.41 -0.03 0.1` and so on.

Comment: Do you really need to use loops and iterations? What is the end goal?

Comment: Yes, because each list is a configuration in the original code and inside two loops, some scripts are called to get the values. Here I just showed those values with `cnt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use you loop (I still don't get why), here is how to fix it:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
cnt = 0
for l2 in range(len(list2)):
    vec = []
    for l1 in range(len(list1)):
        vec.append(cnt)
        cnt += 1
    tmp = pd.DataFrame([vec], index=[list2[l2]])
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, tmp], axis=0)
    print(df1, end='\n\n')
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3
A  0  1  2  3

   0  1  2  3
A  0  1  2  3
B  4  5  6  7

   0  1   2   3
A  0  1   2   3
B  4  5   6   7
C  8  9  10  11
```

#### alternative

probably much more efficient, collect all the data and create the DataFrame in the end:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']


cnt = 0
d = {}
for l2 in range(len(list2)):
    vec = []
    for l1 in range(len(list1)):
        vec.append(cnt)
        cnt += 1
    d[list2[l2]] = vec
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

output:

```
   0  1   2   3
A  0  1   2   3
B  4  5   6   7
C  8  9  10  11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a list comprehension inside the dataframe generation (assuming that `foo()` returns a list of `len(list1)` values):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([foo() for _ in range(len(list2))], columns=list1, index=list2)
```

Or if `foo()` only returns a single value at a time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[foo() for i in range(len(list1))] for j in range(len(list2))],
                  columns=list1, index=list2)
```

Should `foo()` be a counter, the result would be:

```
   1  2   3   4
A  0  1   2   3
B  4  5   6   7
C  8  9  10  11
```

Comment: Well I agree with that but please see my comment in the first post. The values to be written are not counter based. Here I used that to create a snippet.

Comment: @mahmood so where are the values coming from?

Comment: Assume `cnt = foo()` and then `vec.append(cnt)`. So a row will be like `A 0.2 0.41 -0.03 0.1`. and  so on.

Comment: @mahmood I've also added code for a version of `foo()` which only returns one value at a time

Answer (score 0):

You may can create the dataframe without loop

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(-1,4), columns = list1, index = list2)
Out[14]: 
   1  2   3   4
A  0  1   2   3
B  4  5   6   7
C  8  9  10  11
```